# Angular material md-form-field, z-index of neighboring span not being respected

Tags: css, angular-material2

I have an md-form-field with an input positioned just before a . The span is pulled up 15px via a negative margin-top. The problem is that I cannot click on that span, it seems like a regular ol' z-index issue but alas changing the z-index of their element in question and I cannot make it behave.

I have been entirely unable to get even a simple plnkr working with themed angular material components despite lots of googling (would be grateful to anyone who could share) but hoping someone can suggest what may be wrong without a solid live example.

```
<md-form-field>
        <input mdInput placeholder="the input">
</md-form-field>
<span> clickable element </span>


span {
      display: block;
      margin-top: -15px;
      cursor: pointer;
}

md-form-field {
   width: 100%;
}
```

The form-field behaves perfectly, as does the span. If I take out the negative margin-top the cursor works correctly. The problem is if I apply the negative margin (so that the span shows up directly underneath the input) part of the md-form-field scaffolded dom elements cover it. I tried applying a small z-index to the md-form-field and the input, and a huge one to the span, but no matter what the md-form-field takes up space below it and hovering over the span does not show a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake as usual, z-index only applies to elements that are explicitly set to fixed, relative, or absolute positioning. Simply changing my span to position: relative now makes z-index behave.

```
span {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   margin-top: -15px;
   cursor: pointer;
}

md-form-field {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I can be much help here but I believe this achieves the effect you were after...

```css
span {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

md-form-field {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<md-form-field>
  <input mdInput placeholder="the input">
  <span> clickable element </span>
</md-form-field>
```

Comment: nah I don't want to set its parent to absolute, but your answer did set me down the right track so thank you for that...

Comment: @JoshuaOhana no worries :)